# Why am I missing template arguments?

Tags: c++

I created a template and gave it a default type:

```
template <typename T = unsigned>
class Network {
    // ...
}
```

However, when I try to instantiate a `Network` object

```
Network nw;
```

I get an error:

```
app.cpp:60:9: error: missing template arguments before 'nw'
```

Line 60 is `Network nw;`. Why am I missing template arguments if I specified that type `T` should default to `unsigned` when no type is explicitly mentioned?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's still a templated type, so it still needs the angle brackets:

```
Network<> nw;
```

Annoying? Yeah.

Comment: According to what I'm seeing with the timestamps, I won by 2 seconds :)

Comment: @Cornstalks: You did, I was watching.

Comment: Bummer, how do you see an exact time stamp?

Comment: put your mouse over the time, you can see it

Comment: hahaha, amazing 2 seconds! but i wrote 2 seconds more stuff :p Well done Cornstalks

Comment: @Ben: Ha it was a close one!

Comment: The most exciting of all the races, move over F1, this is SO racing, extreme!

Answer (score 8):

It still needs to be:

```
Network<> nw;
```

even though it is default it still needs to be called like a template.